# How to find what range a given number falls using Object

Tags: javascript, range

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oaxgzsr1/

By the way, the random isn't actually a random number but a variable. Sorry about that.

Script:

```
  var random = 5;
  var rangeof = "";

  /* option #1 */
  if (random > 0 && random <= 5)
  rangeof = "1-5";
  if (random > 5 && random <= 10)
  rangeof = "6-10";
  if (random > 10 && random <= 15)
  rangeof = "10-15";
  if (random > 15 && random <= 20)
  rangeof = "16-20";
  if (random > 20 && random <= 25)
  rangeof = "21-25";
  //and so forth until we hit 100


  /* option #2 */
  var ranges = {
  1: "1-5",
  2: "1-5",
  3: "1-5",
  4: "1-5",
  5: "1-5",
  6: "6-10",
  7: "6-10",
  8: "6-10",
  9: "6-10",
  10: "6-10"
  //and so forth until we hit 100
  };

  alert(ranges[5]);
```

As you can see it can get lengthy and very hard to maintain.

Is there any possible way I can do something like this:

```
  var ranges = {
    1-5: "1-5",
    6-10: "6-10",
    11-15: "11-15",
    16-20: "16-20"
  }
```

So for any given number, I can pull the key value out using the range.

For example:

if number is 7, it falls within `6-10` key range and the value I would get is `6-10`.

Comment: Write a loop to create an array over whatever range of input numbers is applicable, and populate it with arrays of two values (the lower and upper ends of the ranges). Then you can use your lookup technique.

Comment: If the intervals are consistently 5, as appears from your description, then why not just a bit of arithmetic to work out where a number falls? E.g. `Math.floor(7/5)*5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the logic always the same and monothonic? Then you can do it as this:

```js
const range = 5;

function inWhatRange(num) {
   const multiple = Math.floor( (num-1) / range);
   return `${multiple*range + 1}-${(multiple+1)*range}`;
}

console.log(inWhatRange(3));
console.log(inWhatRange(5));
console.log(inWhatRange(10));
console.log(inWhatRange(11));
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't clarify. The `random` variable is just any number not a random generated number. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Si8 - I am asking if you need custom ranges such as `1-5`, `6-17`, `18-33` or its always the same as you described

Comment: It's always same... so `1-5`, `,6-10`... etc. That range will always remain the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Si8 - then no updates needed, what I posted will always work as expected

Comment: Your seems the most efficient way of accomplishing it. I will accept your answer. I upvoted all the other answer as those are also other ways I could've accomplished my task. Thank you and everyone else for their help!

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the interval for a random number.

```js
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1),
    size = 5,
    slot = Math.floor((random - 1) / size),
    interval = [slot * size + 1, (slot + 1) * size].join('-');

console.log(random, interval);
```

Comment: @libik, it should so now.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple function for that. 
Just iterate inside your ranges with a specific range step and check the min/max.

```js
const startRange = 1;
const endRange = 20;
const rangeStep = 4;

function getNumberRange(number){
  for(let i = startRange; i<endRange; i+=rangeStep+1){
    if(number >= i && number <= i+rangeStep){ 
      console.log(`${number} range: ${i}-${i+rangeStep}`);
    }
  }
}


getNumberRange(3);
getNumberRange(5);
getNumberRange(10);
getNumberRange(11);
```

Comment: Whats the chance that we randomly selected the same numbers to test with :)

Comment: Ahah so funny, a random number is not really random. We've same brain compiler... @libik And you answered 10 sec after me...

Answer (score 2):

A basic calculation will find the bucket that a value falls in:

```
var x = 7;

var lower = Math.floor((x - 1) / 5) * 5;
var upper = lower + 5;
var range = (lower + 1) + "-" + upper; // "6-10"
```

Comment: Author asked for `6-10`, not `5-10`

Answer (score 2):

Little late to the party but this works as well

```
   function getRange(x, interval, start, end) {
      if(x < interval) {
        console.log("range is " + start + " - " + interval);
      } else {
        var set = Math.ceil(x/interval);
        console.log("range is " + ((set * interval) - (interval - 1)) + " - " + set * interval)
      }
    }

    getRange(26, 5, 1, 100) // "range is 26 - 30"
    getRange(5, 5, 1, 100) // "range is 1 - 5"
    getRange(12, 5, 1, 100) // "range is 11 - 15"
```

Comment: Wow your solution goes way beyond... Thank you!!!! I +1 your answer. It's never late my friend

Answer (score 1):

you could use a chain of ifs:

```js
let random = Math.round(Math.random() * 99 + 1) // I assume the number is never below 1
let rangeof


if (random < 6)
  rangeof = "1-5"
else if (random < 15)
  rangeof = "6-14"
else if (random < 100)
  rangeof = "15-99"
  
console.log(rangeof)
```

Or just store your bounds in an array (assuming there is no empty interval) and iterate over them:

```js
let bounds = [1, 6, 15, 60, 100]
let random = Math.round(Math.random() * 99 + 1)
let rangeof


upper = bounds.findIndex(bound => bound > random)
if (upper == 0) throw 'bad number, should be a positive integer' 
if (upper == -1) throw `bad number, should be lower than ${bounds[bounds.length - 1]}`
rangeof = bounds[upper - 1] + '-' + (bounds[upper] - 1)

console.log(`${random} is in ${rangeof}`)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid a chain of `if`s because it can get lengthy and let's say it's not 5 anymore, but 4, then I would have to edit it again.

Comment: Oh you range are separated 5 by 5? Then you could look at one of the other answers. Mine is for varying ranges